# Mongo Aggregation query is slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We are using mongodb for all our analytic queries. Below i have pasted the query plan of one of the queries. The collection has around 1.3 million entries and this query runs on one mapping (which can have max 40k entries) which is specified as **assignment_supply_entity_mapping_id** in the match pipeline. This query is currently taking 553ms despite an IXSCAN on **assignment_supply_entity_mapping_id**.

My question is, isn't the time taken, a bit on higher side, considering the amount of data being queried. If so, how do i optimise it? I suspect, the nested filter is the cause. Is this true?

```
{  
   "op":"command",
   "ns":"analytics_new.leads",
   "command":{  
      "aggregate":"leads",
      "pipeline":[  
         {  
            "$project":{  
               "logs":0
            }
         },
         {  
            "$match":{  
               "$and":[  
                  {  
                     "assignment_supply_entity_mapping_id":{  
                        "$in":[  
                           1011,
                           850,
                           998,
                           840
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "tags.is_duplicate":{  
                        "$ne":true
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "tags.is_abandoned":{  
                        "$ne":true
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "tags.is_archived":{  
                        "$ne":true
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":{  
                        "$nin":[  

                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     "$or":[  
                        {  
                           "all_agents":{  
                              "$in":[  
                                 2765,
                                 2766,
                                 193,
                                 994,
                                 1007,
                                 1188,
                                 1376,
                                 1769,
                                 2421,
                                 2422,
                                 2423,
                                 2424,
                                 115,
                                 133,
                                 149,
                                 193,
                                 441,
                                 747,
                                 884,
                                 994,
                                 1003,
                                 1007,
                                 1100,
                                 1188,
                                 1378,
                                 1612,
                                 1769,
                                 1964,
                                 1966,
                                 1967,
                                 1968,
                                 1969,
                                 1970,
                                 1971,
                                 1973,
                                 2333,
                                 2364,
                                 3170,
                                 3318,
                                 3320,
                                 3757,
                                 4071,
                                 4294,
                                 4297,
                                 1965,
                                 1188,
                                 994,
                                 193,
                                 715,
                                 1599,
                                 2333,
                                 3170,
                                 2424,
                                 1972,
                                 1007,
                                 2423,
                                 1377,
                                 1378,
                                 1970,
                                 1100,
                                 649,
                                 1950,
                                 1376,
                                 441,
                                 1612,
                                 939,
                                 1966,
                                 1971,
                                 133,
                                 1952,
                                 1969,
                                 337,
                                 1973,
                                 712,
                                 3318,
                                 2392,
                                 115,
                                 708,
                                 1037,
                                 1964,
                                 2421,
                                 1967,
                                 537,
                                 1769,
                                 1968,
                                 1956,
                                 3320,
                                 2364,
                                 978,
                                 1974,
                                 149,
                                 996,
                                 1003,
                                 1951,
                                 2610,
                                 2422,
                                 884
                              ]
                           }
                        },
                        {  
                           "$and":[  
                              {  
                                 "agent.id":{  
                                    "$exists":false
                                 }
                              },
                              {  
                                 "$or":[  
                                    {  
                                       "$and":[  
                                          {  
                                             "current_status.id":5
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "$or":[  
                                                {  
                                                   "recently_contacted_agent_ids":{  
                                                      "$exists":false
                                                   }
                                                },
                                                {  
                                                   "recently_contacted_agent_ids":{  
                                                      "$in":[  
                                                         2765,
                                                         2766,
                                                         193,
                                                         994,
                                                         1007,
                                                         1188,
                                                         1376,
                                                         1769,
                                                         2421,
                                                         2422,
                                                         2423,
                                                         2424,
                                                         115,
                                                         133,
                                                         149,
                                                         193,
                                                         441,
                                                         747,
                                                         884,
                                                         994,
                                                         1003,
                                                         1007,
                                                         1100,
                                                         1188,
                                                         1378,
                                                         1612,
                                                         1769,
                                                         1964,
                                                         1966,
                                                         1967,
                                                         1968,
                                                         1969,
                                                         1970,
                                                         1971,
                                                         1973,
                                                         2333,
                                                         2364,
                                                         3170,
                                                         3318,
                                                         3320,
                                                         3757,
                                                         4071,
                                                         4294,
                                                         4297,
                                                         1965,
                                                         1188,
                                                         994,
                                                         193,
                                                         715,
                                                         1599,
                                                         2333,
                                                         3170,
                                                         2424,
                                                         1972,
                                                         1007,
                                                         2423,
                                                         1377,
                                                         1378,
                                                         1970,
                                                         1100,
                                                         649,
                                                         1950,
                                                         1376,
                                                         441,
                                                         1612,
                                                         939,
                                                         1966,
                                                         1971,
                                                         133,
                                                         1952,
                                                         1969,
                                                         337,
                                                         1973,
                                                         712,
                                                         3318,
                                                         2392,
                                                         115,
                                                         708,
                                                         1037,
                                                         1964,
                                                         2421,
                                                         1967,
                                                         537,
                                                         1769,
                                                         1968,
                                                         1956,
                                                         3320,
                                                         2364,
                                                         978,
                                                         1974,
                                                         149,
                                                         996,
                                                         1003,
                                                         1951,
                                                         2610,
                                                         2422,
                                                         884
                                                      ]
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             ]
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    },
                                    {  
                                       "current_status.id":{  
                                          "$in":[  
                                             4,
                                             1,
                                             2,
                                             12
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {  
            "$group":{  
               "_id":{  
                  "channel":"$lead_origin"
               },
               "booking_done":{  
                  "$sum":{  
                     "$cond":[  
                        {  
                           "$and":[  
                              {  
                                 "$ne":[  
                                    {  
                                       "$type":"$status_timestamps.booking_done_timestamp"
                                    },
                                    "missing"
                                 ]
                              },
                              {  
                                 "$gt":[  
                                    "$status_timestamps.booking_done_timestamp",
                                    "$status_timestamps.failed_timestamp"
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        1,
                        0
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "failed":{  
                  "$sum":{  
                     "$cond":[  
                        {  
                           "$ne":[  
                              {  
                                 "$type":"$status_timestamps.failed_timestamp"
                              },
                              "missing"
                           ]
                        },
                        1,
                        0
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "failed_after_visit":{  
                  "$sum":{  
                     "$cond":[  
                        {  
                           "$and":[  
                              {  
                                 "$and":[  
                                    {  
                                       "$ne":[  
                                          {  
                                             "$type":"$status_timestamps.failed_timestamp"
                                          },
                                          "missing"
                                       ]
                                    },
                                    {  
                                       "$ne":[  
                                          {  
                                             "$type":"$status_timestamps.visit_done_timestamp"
                                          },
                                          "missing"
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 ]
                              },
                              {  
                                 "$gt":[  
                                    "$status_timestamps.failed_timestamp",
                                    "$status_timestamps.visit_done_timestamp"
                                 ]
                              }
                           ]
                        },
                        1,
                        0
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "junk":{  
                  "$sum":{  
                     "$cond":[  
                        {  
                           "$ne":[  
                              {  
                                 "$type":"$status_timestamps.junk_timestamp"
                              },
                              "missing"
                           ]
                        },
                        1,
                        0
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "received":{  
                  "$sum":1
               },
               "visit_done":{  
                  "$sum":{  
                     "$cond":[  
                        {  
                           "$ne":[  
                              {  
                                 "$type":"$status_timestamps.visit_done_timestamp"
                              },
                              "missing"
                           ]
                        },
                        1,
                        0
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ],
      "cursor":{  

      },
      "$db":"analytics_new"
   },
   "keysExamined":31080,
   "docsExamined":31076,
   "cursorExhausted":true,
   "numYield":249,
   "locks":{  
      "Global":{  
         "acquireCount":{  
            "r":NumberLong(508)
         }
      },
      "Database":{  
         "acquireCount":{  
            "r":NumberLong(254)
         }
      },
      "Collection":{  
         "acquireCount":{  
            "r":NumberLong(254)
         }
      }
   },
   "nreturned":6,
   "responseLength":905,
   "protocol":"op_query",
   "millis":553,
   "planSummary":"IXSCAN { assignment_supply_entity_mapping_id: 1, created_at: -1 }",
   "ts":   ISODate("2019-03-04T08:28:57.143   Z"),
   "client":"172.31.18.209",
   "allUsers":[  

   ],
   "user":""
}
```

Comment: how many documents does the first `$match` return? `"$match":{  
               "$and":[  { "assignment_supply_entity_mapping_id":{   "$in":[  ... ] } },` and how long does that take to run (as a simple query)?

Comment: It returns 25998 documents when i run db.find(match_query).count().Its taking 216ms to execute. I checked the ``executionTimeInMillis`` in ``executionStats``. Also Isn't this on higher side as well? shouldn't the IXSCAN for this much documents be faster?

Comment: It depends on how big the documents are, how busy is the database with other operations, etc.. Try to create an index only on `assignment_supply_entity_mapping_id: 1` maybe that will reduce the size of the index and therefore the scan.
After that maybe also try to create a sparse index https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/

Comment: Thanks for the response. `assignment_supply_entity_mapping_id` will be present in every document, for sure, so sparse index will not help here and compound index of `{assignment_supply_entity_mapping_id: 1, created_at: -1}` will roughly have the same size as that of a index on `assignment_supply_entity_mapping_id: 1`. 

The load on the server is also not that big. 

The size of document is my concern as well, currently the avgObjectSize is around 5KB. Is this big enough? I also reduced the size of the doc to 2KB(avg), but still didn't find any significant improvement.

Comment: how big is the database? does it all fit in RAM? here are some useful links: 
 https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#must-my-working-set-size-fit-ram https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/

Comment: The sample database i am using to analyse these queries has `dataSize` of around 8.5GB, `indexSize` of around 360MB. The collection used in the query has `dataSize` of around 6GB and `indexSize` around 270MB. The system has 8GB RAM.

Comment: Any suggestions? I have tried a-lot of things but nothing seems to be working. What could be wrong?

Comment: no idea. maybe send me an email at hi@gian.xyz